# Angular 4 - Checking one checkbox checks them all

Tags: forms, angular, angular-ngmodel

Not sure how to fix this. I want to have an array of strings based on a checkbox form. I have all the values set to be added to the same array (MenteeLevelPrefernce), but when I check one box they all get checked. What am I doing wrong here?

```
        <label for="mentorPrefCheck">Mentee Level Preference (select all that apply)</label>
        <div class="form-group" id="mentorPrefCheck">
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" id="hsLevelCheck" [(ngModel)]="mentor.MenteeLevelPreference" name="menteeLevelPreference" value="Highscool"> Highschool</label>
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" id="undergradLevelCheck" [(ngModel)]="mentor.MenteeLevelPreference" name="menteeLevelPreference"  value="Undergraduate"> Undergraduate</label>
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" id="gradLevelCheck" [(ngModel)]="mentor.MenteeLevelPreference" name="menteeLevelPreference" value="Graduate"> Graduate</label>
        </div>
```

Comment: Because your two way binding for the input boxes all point to the same variable

Answer (score 0):

use unique variables for [(ngModel)] and name attributes

```
<div class="form-group" id="mentorPrefCheck">
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" id="hsLevelCheck" [(ngModel)]="mentor.MenteeLevelPreference1" name="menteeLevelPreference1" value="Highscool"> Highschool</label>
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" id="undergradLevelCheck" [(ngModel)]="mentor.MenteeLevelPreference2" name="menteeLevelPreference2"  value="Undergraduate"> Undergraduate</label>
          <label class="checkbox-inline">
            <input type="checkbox" id="gradLevelCheck" [(ngModel)]="mentor.MenteeLevelPreference3" name="menteeLevelPreference3" value="Graduate"> Graduate</label>
        </div>
```